# Can removal of adhesive tape damage a tile?

Tags: walls, tile, light-fixture, adhesive, taping

I bought some small lights that attach to the wall with adhesive tape/sticker (3M).
The label on the box says:

> Caution: Adhesive tape may remove paint or damage surface when removed

If the tape is attached to tiles is there a chance that there could be some kind of damage done upon removal?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about glazed ceramic tiles, then the probability of damage is very very low. (There's still the possibility of scratches, if you attack the tile with a blade, but that's not the fault of the tape.)

The only exception I can think of is a small category of rustic tiles that have a very poorly adhered glaze or no glaze at all, but I doubt those would be on the wall.

Comment: By glazed you mean the tiles that are "shiny"/have a glare right?

Comment: Yes, shiny is definitely glazed. There are also some matte glazes, but even these are much more shiny than raw ceramics.

Comment: So rustic tiles are raw ceramic? Sorry I don't really know the proper terminology